# Creating an organization in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, organization

I am currently part of several organizations, which I have been previously invited to. I would like to create a new organization solely for myself. According to the documentation (https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/admin/index.html#orgmng) I should be able to go to 'Manage Organizations' and click 'Create an organization', but I do not have this option. How should I go about creating an organization?

Comment: Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Comment: Hi manetsus. I have been trying to create the organization from the UI on console.ng.bluemix.net.

Answer (score 1):

For the public version of Bluemix Trial accounts can only create one organisation (which is created the first time you log in). If you add credit card details and move to a "PayGo" account then you are able to create multiple organisations.

On the dedicated or local deployments of Bluemix all admins are given the permissions to create their own organisations.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I am using public Bluemix, but don't have my own personal organisation. I will speak to Bluemix support to try and obtain one.

Comment: Here is additional information. Add organization is available only if you are the paid accounts (PAYG or Subscription type). See:
 [How do I create a new organization in Bluemix?](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/29214/how-do-i-create-a-new-organization-in-bluemix.html)

Comment: We should revise this answer. Public Subscription owners can create multiple Orgs in their Account. Trial Users can't.

Comment: Edited answer. Thanks guys :D

Answer (score 0):

Only account owners with Pay-As-You-Go accounts can create an organization. You can create an organization by completing the following steps:

- Using Bluemix Web GUI:
- Click Account > Manage Organizations page.
- Click Add a New Org.
- Enter the org name.
- Click Add.

Using Bluemix admin CLI

```
- cf ba create-organization <organization> <manager>
```

Where

`<organization>`: The name or GUID of the Bluemix org to add.

`<manager>`: The user name of the manager for the org.